# Robot Framework GET Request using RequestsLibrary Assertion Error

Tags: python, api, robotframework

When I am trying to assert status code in API Testing using Robot Framework, I got this type of error. Why this error I cant understand. Please tell me if you know, it's will be helpful for me.

```
*** Settings ***

Library  RequestsLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Url_one}      https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=apple&from=2022-04-04&to=2022-04-04&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=e7cdf1ae162b4475bbbee8a4046797a4

*** Test Cases ***

Get_All_Apple_Articles
create session  mysession   ${Url_one}
${response} =   Get Request  mysession  ${Url_one}
log to console  ${response.status_code}
log to console  ${response.content}
log to console  ${response.headers}
${status_code}=  ${response.status_code}

should be equal  ${status_code}     200
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the response code to string then it should work, change your line

```
${status_code}=  ${response.status_code}
```

to:

```
${status_code}=  Convert To String   ${response.status_code}
```

As currently that line is not only incorrect syntax but also will would assign an int which you later compare to string and that would fail